# Recursion on tags in collection

Tags: javascript, reactjs, recursion

I am trying to do recursion on every collection item (see render below where I call the function recursiveTags). Each collection has a hierarchical list of tags of unlimited depth. I am trying to add a simple list of tags to each collection, e.g: "Cartoon > Simpsons family > 2014".

I have given it a try in my recursiveTags function, but am not sure how to approach this. Anyone that can give me a helping hand?

---

**App.js**

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
      super()

      this.state = {
          collectionsarr: collections,
          assetsarr: assets,
          clickedassets: [],
          assetsSortingMode: "sortbyname"
      }
  }

  recursiveTags(elemId){
    let result = this.state.collectionsarr.find(element => element.id === elemId).tags
    let resultarr = []
    console.log(result)
  }
  
  render(){
  return (
          <div className="App">
            <h1>Coding challenge</h1>
            <div className="left">
              {this.state.collectionsarr.map(element => 
                <div key={element.id}>

                  <p>{this.recursiveTags(element.id)}</p>

                </div>
              )}
            </div>
          </div>
        )
  }
}

export default App
```

---

**collections array**

```
const collections = [
    {
        id: 1,
        name: "The Simpsons",
        masterAssetId: 13,
        tags: {
            name: "Cartoon",
            subTag: {
                name: "Simpsons family",
                subTag: {
                    name: "2014",
                },
            },
        },
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        name: "Super heroes",
        masterAssetId: 24,
        tags: {
            name: "DC Super heroes",
            subTag: {
                name: "2014",
            },
        },
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        name: "Toy story",
        masterAssetId: 31,
        tags: {
            name: "Disney",
            subTag: {
                name: "Pixar",
                subTag: {
                    name: "Original movie",
                    subTag: {
                        name: "2010",
                    },
                },
            },
        },
    },
    {
        id: 4,
        name: "Ninjago",
        masterAssetId: 42,
        tags: {
            name: "Ninja",
            subTag: {
                name: "Secret Ninja Force",
                subTag: {
                    name: "2017",
                },
            },
        },
    },
];
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want is a list of tags from your collection object, something like that should work.

```
getAllTagsForCollection(collection){
    const result = [];
    let tagObj = collection.tags;
    while (tagObj) {
        result.push(tagObj.name);
        tagObj = tagObj.subTag;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Sure, but do note how much more elegant a recursive solution is: `const getAllTags = (tags) => [tags.name, ...(tags.subTag ? getAllTags(tags.subTag) : [])]]` or the destructured version in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

It's not quite clear to me what output format you want.  If it's the plain strings that you use in the question, so that the result is a collection of objects that look like this:

```js
    {
        id: 1,
        masterAssetId: 13,
        name: "The Simpsons",
        tags: "Cartoon > Simpsons family > 2014"
    }
```

then this code should do it:

```js
const resolveTag = ({name, subTag}) => 
   name + (subTag ? (` > ${resolveTag(subTag)}`) : ``)

const flattenTags = (collections) =>
  collections .map (({tags, ...rest}) => ({
    ...rest,
    tags: resolveTag(tags)
  }))

const collections = [{id: 1, name: "The Simpsons", masterAssetId: 13, tags: {name: "Cartoon", subTag: {name: "Simpsons family", subTag: {name: "2014"}}}}, {id: 2, name: "Super heroes", masterAssetId: 24, tags: {name: "DC Super heroes", subTag: {name: "2014"}}}, {id: 3, name: "Toy story", masterAssetId: 31, tags: {name: "Disney", subTag: {name: "Pixar", subTag: {name: "Original movie", subTag: {name: "2010"}}}}}, {id: 4, name: "Ninjago", masterAssetId: 42, tags: {name: "Ninja", subTag: {name: "Secret Ninja Force", subTag: {name: "2017"}}}}];


console .log (flattenTags (collections))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {min-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

The recursive function is fairly simple, returning the name, and if the object has a `subTag` node, then appending `' > '` plus the result of recurring on that `subTag`, stopping when there is no `subTag`.

If instead, you want to get something more like this:

```js
    {
        id: 1,
        masterAssetId: 13,
        name: "The Simpsons",
        tags: ["Cartoon", "Simpsons family", "2014"]
    }
```

then we can use the same kind of recursion with a slightly different output structure, as  you can see in this snippet:

```js
const resolveTag = ({name, subTag}) => 
   [name, ...(subTag ? resolveTag (subTag) : [])]

const flattenTags = (collections) =>
  collections .map (({tags, ...rest}) => ({
    ...rest,
    tags: resolveTag(tags)
  }))

const collections = [{id: 1, name: "The Simpsons", masterAssetId: 13, tags: {name: "Cartoon", subTag: {name: "Simpsons family", subTag: {name: "2014"}}}}, {id: 2, name: "Super heroes", masterAssetId: 24, tags: {name: "DC Super heroes", subTag: {name: "2014"}}}, {id: 3, name: "Toy story", masterAssetId: 31, tags: {name: "Disney", subTag: {name: "Pixar", subTag: {name: "Original movie", subTag: {name: "2010"}}}}}, {id: 4, name: "Ninjago", masterAssetId: 42, tags: {name: "Ninja", subTag: {name: "Secret Ninja Force", subTag: {name: "2017"}}}}];

console .log (flattenTags (collections))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {min-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```